# How to apply video filters in flutter like tiktok or instagram?

Tags: flutter, video, flutter-video-player, tiktok

I am building app like tiktok and want to implement that functionality in that app. Please help me. Also how to use tapioca: ^1.0.2 package to apply that filter, because there is no proper documentation.
Also there is no video tutorials - please give me direction.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter doesn't support native video processing effects and filters the way TikTok does because Flutter is not a native framework.

To achieve effects and filters like TikTok, you need to use cloud apis or make a native Flutter plugin yourself.

You can apply normal filters like brightness, exposure, and contrast with [this limited camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera).